# ブラウザアプリで違うユーザーが編集しているデータを「違うユーザーが表示している」とリアルタイムに表示したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, socket.io

Vue.jsのブラウザアプリを開発しています。
ユーザーから、ユーザーAとユーザーBの見ている同じ画面のデータをOffice365やGoogle Driveのように例えば
「今ユーザーAがこのデータを編集中です。」
などと表示してほしい、と言われました。

どのようにするのが一番よいやり方かご教示いただけないでしょうか？
今のところ考えているのは、Nodeとsocket.io を使う方法です。
他の方法でよいものがあれば教えてください。

Comment: もう少し詳細に要件をいただけますか？リアルタイムとは完全に同期をとる必要がありますか？それともある程度の遅延は許されますか？分単位ぐらいのずれはOKとか？同時に何人ぐらいの人が一つのデータに触る可能性がありますか？一人二人？それとも100人レベル？

Comment: ありがとうございます！
リアルタイムは、一応5秒おき程度でよいと言われています。一度に編集する人は40人程度です。